# How to return only part of JSON object from REST API with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

So I've been trying to figure out a way to return only a specific key-value pair from a REST API call using JQuery. The initial call I'm going off of is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://BASEURL/api/project-type/list-all",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function ()
    {
        $('#projectTypeListLoading').text("Loading...");
    },
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR)
    {
        var trHTML = "";
        $.each(data, function (i, item)
        {
            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.Name + '</td><td>' + item.Code + '</td><td>'
                + item.Order + '</td><td>' + item.IsActive + '</td><td>' + item.Id + '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#projectTypesTable').append(trHTML);
        $('#projectTypeListLoading').html("DONE");
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, status)
    {
        $('#projectTypeListLoading').html("Error loading list");
    }
});
```

With this I can get a list of JSON Objects from my REST API like so:

```
[{"Name":"Project Type 2","Code":"2","Order":2,"IsActive":true,"Id":"c497e4e8-16b4-44e2-b6ac-a9a2c392d9d4"},{"Name":"Project Type 3","Code":"3","Order":3,"IsActive":true,"Id":"6da2a240-2327-4260-a6df-f4bec25535c2"}]
```

I then use these in my Ajax success portion and stick them in a table. Works perfectly. However, what I would like to have happen is to ONLY get say the Name key-value pair part of the JSON Object as the Response from my REST API. Like so:

```
[{"Name":"Project Type 2"},{"Name":"Project Type 3"]
```

And then in my Success function use:

```
success: function (data, status, jqXHR)
    {
        var trHTML = "";
        $.each(data, function (i, item)
        {
            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.Name + '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#projectTypesTable').append(trHTML);
        $('#projectTypeListLoading').html("DONE");
    },
```

I could achieve this result in two different ways. I could:

- Change my REST API call to 'https://BASEURL/api/project-type/name'. And call this and have the API only return the name. I don't want to do this because I have 20 different urls which already return all, I will not be making a separate URL to access each key-value individually for each of these.
- Get all like in my initial example then just ignore every key-value pair that isn't 'Name'. This would do what I want but the point is there will be many hundreds of these calls going on. Each of these calls would return the full JSON object then I'd cut that down; that's a lot of unnecessary chatter. I'd rather be able to specify which key-value pair I want to reduce server load.

Any advice on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy answer to this with REST endpoints. This is the exact problem that [GraphQL](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/05/01/graphql-introduction.html), [Falcor](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor), [OData](http://www.odata.org/) and a number of other libraries were created to assist with.